# Do selecting directly from table and selecting from view have the same performance impact

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Assume I have the following tables and view;

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(
 EMPID NUMBER(3,0),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
 DEPARTMENTID NUMBER(2,0)

);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS
(
  DEPARTMENTID NUMBER(2,0),
  DEPNAME VARCHAR2(50),
);

CREATE VIEW EMD_DEP AS
SELECT EMP.EMPID,EMP.LAST_NAME,EMP.FIRST_NAME,DEP.DEPNAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP NATURAL JOIN
       DEPARTMENTS DEP;
```

Now are these below two queries the same performance-wise? :

```
1. SELECT * FROM EMP_DEP WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE 'A%';
2. SELECT EMP.EMPID,EMP.LAST_NAME,EMP.FIRST_NAME,DEP.DEPNAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP NATURAL JOIN
          DEPARTMENTS DEP
          WHERE EMP.LAST_NAME LIKE 'A%';
```

I tested and both queries execute in 0.016 seconds. But I thought selecting from the view must be bit slower as (I thought) SQL engine first has to select all the rows from the joined tables and then again apply a second query to filter it. Was I wrong?

Comment: It should not differ as view is a stored query

Comment: There can be differences, but you would not see them for such a simple query.  Your understanding of how views work in Oracle is not correct.

Comment: Does this mean that the difference will be quite noticeable if query is much more complex?

Comment: This is a very difficult question that probably won't get a proper answer here.  In an ideal world, Oracle can use optimizer transformations to re-write two logically identical queries to use the same execution plan.  Specifically in this case, it would use **predicate pushing**, which would almost certainly work with this example.  But in the real world, there are limitations to predicate pushing.  At some point the view may contain a feature that prevents predicate pushing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Toad you can simple look at the Explain Plan to see if there is a difference.
I don't think there will, since your assumption that it executes the View and than executes the other where clause is just wrong.
Oracle (and I think every other Database) takes the whole thing, analyzes what's the best way to execute it and than just executes it. That is the whole point of using SQL.
The only way to tell Oracle in which order it should perform the steps is by using hints.

Comment: I've actually looked at the explain plan and seen that both are the same. But I'm not sure whether this will always be true.

Comment: You never can really be sure, what oracle does with your statements unless you use a ton of hints, but I never heard, that views would have any performance-disadvantages and I did some big data operations with views.

Answer (score 1):

You will not see any differences because the query is too small, one of the benefits you have when you use views that oracle has parsed and analyzed this query already. If you have a big query Oracle has to spend some time to parse and analyze it. Read [Oracle Contents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm) it is very helpful.